# Database in C language for MS-DOS?

Tags: c, dos

Requirement:
I am having a CSV file which can contain max of 2000 records or less.
Here each record means one row.
Each row consists of Device id and consumer name and address and device make.
Whenever any of consumer present in the list is serviced i need to update the time stamp of service.

These requirement are to be implemented in ANSI C language for MS-DOS , and IDE for development is Borland C 3.1.

Update:

1. I cannot change the platform or ide, because these requirement are added to existing code which is having dependency with the Borland c 3.1 ide.
2. I am not not supposed to use any commercial products.
3. Two or three search keys.

4.CPU specs of my end device is

Processor       :    Intel 80C386 EX

Operating System :    /BIOS MS-DOS 6.22 / SANDS BIOS

Memory           :    3.5 MB SRAM ( upto 16.5 MB)

Comment: Google dbase. I believe it exists for C.

Comment: Just clarifying - You need to convert an existing `csv` file (`comma-separated-variable`) to a database, and create an application in C, specifically using Borland.  Are there any of these specs flexible? i.e. could you settle for a compiler that is current (i.e. that complies with at least C99,C11)?

Comment: If you had asked this question 20 years ago, there would have been many answers. There was Btrieve, Paradox, dBase, FoxBase, and many others. Nowadays you might be able to find one of those, but I doubt you'd be able to get a new license or support.

Comment: How many different search keys do you need?

Comment: I suggest you use search terms like `"B tree C library MS-DOS"` or `"hash table C library MS-DOS"`.  All the actual database libraries from that era were commercial as far as I know.  Also, for your application is GPL software okay or do you need a commercial-friendly license on whatever you find?  (I'd suggest buying a license for Btrieve or something if I thought you could actually find someone still selling licenses to the old software.)

Comment: Also: Is this for a school project where you're supposed to implement this database, or are you actually working on an application which runs on a literal 8086 processor?

Comment: Your requirements are poorly described.  If it's simply necessary to update the CSV file, changing certain fields, a simple scan and replace algorithm is much more appropriate than using a DB.  If you do need DB functions you need to describe your application requirements much better.

Comment: Thanks for the input,my requirement will be satsified by using the B tree or HASH tables.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search seems to indicate that SQLite will work as a library on MS-DOS. [Check out this link](http://www.bttr-software.de/forum/board_entry.php?id=12278).

Comment: That would be a 32-bit version, requiring a 386 or better. OP specifies a requirement for 8086.

Comment: You are correct that he stated that. I assumed he simply meant an x86 processor, but that may likely be an invalid assumption in this case.

Comment: A clever person could probably port a limited function version of SQLite to 8086.  But it would be more trouble than its worth for the simple problem described.

Comment: A clever person will crank out an ANSI C program that uses only the C library and be done with it. You don't need SQ-anything for < 2000 records.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a database library to handle 2000 records with four fields. Even on an 8088 PC with 640K of memory, this data can be handled in memory by a C program.  For that matter, should be able to easily load this data into any decent DOS text editor like Qedit.

Just allocate some `struct`s for the records. An array of some 2000 pointers to these records can be subject to `sqort` to create a sorted index which can be `bsearch`-ed. You can use several such arrays to create sorted indices on different fields.

Or implement some simple hashing.

But even linear searching through less than 2000 records will probably be okay.

Do you know that some BASIC interpreters on 8 bit microcomputers used a linked list linear search through the lines of program code to implement GOTO?  A forward GOTO (to a line number greater than the current one) would scan from the current line; a backwards goto would start searching from the beginning of the program. Yet programs of several thousand lines ran fine.

Choose a "large" or "huge" memory model; the data isn't going all going to fit into a 64 kB segment.